# How can I make a server using java or PHP to send info to several Java clients?

Tags: java, php, multithreading, sockets, client

I want my PHP server to send info to one or more java clients.
each Java client has an ID, how can the server know which client will receive this info without checking all the clients' IDs.

I did some research and I think I need to use sockets and multi threads but I am a beginner in Java,PHP and networks, I need some guidance.

So,  how can the server know which client will receive this info without asking each  client for its IDs.

the server will send to the java(android)clients without their request.

I solved this problem by using a push notification service...thank you all for your help

Comment: At a basic level, this is usually done with [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Comment: question is not clear. what you want to do network programming OR web programming??

Comment: You need some mean to identify one given client from the rest. If not the client ID, you would still need some unique feature which each client has to be able to identify them from the rest.

Comment: @Jared Farrish, I do not think sessions has anything to do with my case

Comment: @ Yogesh Suthar it is a web based php app sending info to the java android client whenever there is info for this client. So, the client won't send request to the server. the server will send to clients the info they must receive

Comment: @user1494142 For this kind of application you have to write code for each android device at server side for sending information and use ajax-jquery to send request from android device and use multithreading in android device also for gathering info from server.

Comment: Sounds like [push notification](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5695867/451969). There's [libraries in many flavors](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a server listens and responds to requests. The requests coming from your
clients would include their IDs, so the server would know who is was responding to.

Comment: the server will send when required, the client will never request the info

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in such scenarios, you would go with a [publish-subscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) mechansim where the publisher, your PHP program in this case, will publish the data intended to be consumed by clients, to a channel. The subscribers, java programs in your case, will subscribe to this channel representing using a topic/id and consume the data. This [SO question discussed about a similar scenario for PHP/JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070869/communicating-between-php-and-java-using-activemq-stomp).

Answer (score 0):

Use `CRON JOB` at server side.

It will execute the php script at specific time without client call.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

Try this tutorial.